# Creating view in browser functionality with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, temporary-files

I have been struggling with this problem for a while but can't seem to find a solution for it. The situation is that I need to open a file in browser and after the user closes the file the file is removed from their machine. All I have is the binary data for that file. If it matters, the binary data comes from Google Storage using the `download_as_string` method.

After doing some research I found that the `tempfile` module would suit my needs, but I can't get the tempfile to open in browser because the file only exists in memory and not on the disk. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

This is my code so far:

```
import tempfile
import webbrowser

# grabbing binary data earlier on

temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

temp.name = "example.pdf"
temp.write(binary_data_obj)
temp.close()

webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath(temp.name))
```

When this is run, my computer gives me an error that says that the file cannot be opened since it is empty. I am on a Mac and am using Chrome if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a temporary directory instead:

```
import os
import tempfile
import webbrowser

# I used an existing pdf I had laying around as sample data
with open('c.pdf', 'rb') as fh:
    data = fh.read()

# Gives a temporary directory you have write permissions to.
# The directory and files within will be deleted when the with context exits.
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:

    temp_file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'example.pdf')

    # write a normal file within the temp directory
    with open(temp_file_path, 'wb+') as fh:
        fh.write(data)

    webbrowser.open('file://' + temp_file_path)
```

This worked for me on Mac OS.

Comment: So would c.pdf be example.pdf in my case? Sorry I’m a bit new to file opening and all that.

Comment: No, in your case, you wouldn't need to open an existing file to read data from, you would just use the `binary_data_obj` variable in place of my `data` variable.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, your solution works! Just a question, sometimes the file doesn't open, and other times it does. Any reason for that?

Comment: It could have something to do with the file not being finished writing yet. When you ask the OS to write to a file, it will accept the bytes you give it, and then get around to actually writing it to disk whenever it gets time. This can mean you finish writing to a file and by the time you go to use it, it contains no data and isn't ready to use. I believe you can do `fh.flush()` then `os.fsync(fh.fileno())` to wait until it finishes, although don't use this everywhere because it can be quite slow, only use it where you need to read from a file immediately after writing like this.